# Migrate guest from KVM to VirtualBox

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, virtualbox, lvm

I'm migrating some machines from KVM to VirtualBox for a transitional period while we build our new virtualization environment.

The problem now, the disks are located on a LVM partition, and I have to convert them to a format VirtualBox recognizes. I've found a lot of documentation for the transition on the other direction, but not on this one.

```
qemu-img convert -c /dev/Volume01/Disk -O qcow2 Disk.qcow2
```

The tool seems to do its job, but the disk won't work. On VirtualBox, I get `FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.`. Are there another options?

Comment: Unless you want even more problems when you switch back I'd suggest setting up another KVM host temporarily instead of trying to shoehorn this with VirtualBox.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't, since it's on a Windows Server host. It's the only place I can host the machines right now, and I can't remove the operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dd the volume first:

```
dd if=/dev/Volume01/Disk of=/tmp/image.raw
qemu-img convert -O vdi /tmp/image.raw test.vdi
rm /tmp/image.raw
```

Technically you could give that raw file to VirtualBox, but VDI is its native format.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!. I had a problem removing the Qcow2 disk though, very frustrating: freezes, exceptions... Anyway, it's solved and this disk works ok.

Answer (score 1):

1. It looks like the converted disk does not have a boot loader. You can install one by booting from a LiveCD.
2. As an alternative. I'm not sure it will work, but you could try the raw partition access, i.e. make VirtualBox access the LVM partition directly. [More info](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk)